# Getting count on large table query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, count

This is my first time dealing with Oracle.

I am wanting to "prequery" the database for expected row count.

what I have seen in the code is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM (
    {large query here}
)
```

Would the query created by using regular expressions to break the query up on the `FROM` statement, and instead of `SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2.. FROM` just querying `SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROWCOUNT FROM..` be faster?  I'm not sure if any gains I've tested are due to caching or not.  Thanks

Comment: It could be faster sometimes - if no longer required to return the column values the optimizer might decide that certain tables can be eliminated altogether.  But why would you want to do this anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call the query approach you posted "wrapping the large query" and the regex approach you asked about "modifying the large query".

Modifying the large query will not be any faster.

When you `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of a list of fields, Oracle can sometimes eliminate joins and/or table access steps in the query.  But Oracle will still be able to do all those things even if you wrap the large query.

Wrapping the large query also has the advantage that it will work in basically all cases.  Modifying the large query will not work if the large query contains a `GROUP BY` clause.